# CentOS 6 and Fedora Repositories

Tags: centos, fedora, rpm

I did a Google search and couldn't find the specific answer to my questions.

I know CentOS and Fedora are extremely similar. Would a Fedora repository (i.e. https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/?hl=en&platform=linux&brand=CHFK) work for CentOS? Are there any risks for attempting to install a Fedora repo on CentOS 6?

Comment: I am guessing you are trying to install Chrome on CentOS? http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2013/install-chromium-on-centos-red-hat-rhel/#install-chromium

Comment: CentOS/RHEL and Fedora are actually worlds apart. To paraphrase Mark Twain: RHEL doesn't repeat Fedora's development cycle, but it does rhyme. The technologies they're built from have a lot of overlap but Fedora is a lot quicker to change and isn't as paranoid about preserving ISV certification as RHEL/CentOS is.

Comment: @JoelDavis: Good to know. I'll keep that in mind when lookin at installing software in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS is based on RHEL which is not quite the same as Fedora. As stated on the CentOS [Repository wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories):

> Mixing Fedora repositories with CentOS oriented repositories: Look for 'name=Fedora', vs. 'name=CentOS.(whatever)'. **Fedora repositories are not likely to be compatible with CentOS.** Repositories for other Enterprise Linux distros derived from the same upstream sources are more likely to be compatible, but should still be used with care.

So, RHEL repos are *probably* all right (but should still be used with care) Fedora's are likely not to be.

Comment: Exception being EPEL, I guess.

Comment: @schaiba EPEL is a RHEL product that is just developed by the Fedora Project. It exists basically because RHEL is incompatible with Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't ever want to mix repositories between any of the Red Hat based repositories. You can sometimes take CentOS packages and mix them with RHEL and vice versa but do so with caution!

Typically what I do is take the source RPMs from a package that I find in Fedora and attempt to build it for CentOS. These are the packages that most repositories contain named packageX.src.rpm. These packages are essentially pre-packaged source files along with a RPM .spec file that instructs tools in the developers tool chain on how to build package X.

You can setup your own [RPM Build environment](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-rpm-build-environment-on-rhel-redhat-fedora-centos/) fairly easily, and then rebuild the download SRPM. Generally once you have this working you can use commands like this to do the heavy lifting:

```
$ rpmbuild --rebuild packageX.src.rpm
```

If the package has a number of requirements that are needed to build it you can use this command to install them:

```
$ yum-builddep --nogpgcheck packageX.src.rpm
```

There is a more thorough tutorial here, titled: [[one-liner]: Using yum-builddep to Speed Up the Building of SRPMs on Fedora & CentOS](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/8297/one-liner-using-yum-builddep-to-speed-up-the-building-of-srpms-on-fedora-centos/#more-8297).

I have a fair amount of this [documented on my blog](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/?s=rpm%20build) (shameless plug).